# Issue with accessing static from outside c++ library

Tags: c++, opengl-es, box2d

I am working on a project, in this project I have the following...

## Project 1

**JNIBox2DWorld.h**

```
static b2World* world = NULL;
```

**JNIBox2DWorld.cpp**

```
world = new b2World(gravity);
```

Now this seems to work fine but I want to add a OpenGL renderer so I create a new project and referance the old header file....

## Project2

**b2GLPolygonShape.h**

```
#include <Box2D/JNIBox2DWorld.h>
...
class b2GLPolygonShape 
{
  public:
    void Draw();
    void Draw(b2PolygonShape* s);
};
```

**b2GLPolygonShape.cpp**

```
#include "b2GLPolygonShape.h"
void b2GLPolygonShape::Draw(){
LOGD("in Draw");
if(world == NULL){
    LOGD("World is not set for some reason");
}
else{
    LOGD("World is set");
}
}
```

I see that the world works within the Box2D library but when I try to access it via my new code it is null....

> D/Native  (14119): in Draw
>
> D/Native  (14119): World is not set for some reason

Why does it show as null when I call it from my new Library but works fine from the old? Since it is static shouldn't it work with both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be a bit confused about what static does. When you declare a global static variable within a compilation unit (usually a cpp file), this means that that variable is *local* to the compilation unit and *cannot* be seen elsewhere.

Since you are declaring a global static variable within a header file that gets included in two separate cpp files, this ultimately leads to two very different (compilation unit local) global variables named `world`. However, the `world` variable created within `b2GLPolygonShape.cpp` has nothing to do with the variable created in `JNIBox2DWorld.cpp`.

What you probably wanted to do is to declare an external variable in your header file:

**example.h**

```
extern b2World* world;
```

and in one, but only one(!), cpp file create the object:

**example.cpp**

```
b2World* world = new b2World(gravity);
```

In another cpp file you could then use the object:

**test.cpp**

```
#include <example.h>

void foo() {
  world->whatever();
}
```

and at least the linker should be ok.

However, using global variables this way brings in all sorts of trouble (e.g. order of initialization, just to name the most obvious), so you generally should be on the look for
other ways to achieve what you want. You have been warned. Good luck :-)

Comment: Thanks I guess this is what I get for being a Java programmer :-) I will try it out and see if that fixes it.

Comment: I think there may be a different issue due to the fact (as I stated) the cpp files are in separate libraries. When I do as described it doesn't seem to be able to understand world... "b2GLPolygonShape.cpp:6: error: undefined reference to 'world'" I can post my code if needed.

Comment: It might be due to a linking issue because I might not be linking the .so and just using the headers. Let me 2x check